# "SSL Setup for Custom Domains on External Server: Generating SSL Certificates vs. Alternative Approaches"

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, dns, amazon-route53

"In my scenario, users need to direct their custom domains or subdomains to my server's IP address, and I want to know how to ensure SSL for these custom domains. Do I have to create SSL certificates on my server for each custom domain, or is there another way?"

To clarify, you have users who want to use their own custom domains or subdomains to access your server, and you are wondering about the SSL setup for these custom domains. Specifically, you want to know if you need to generate SSL certificates for each custom domain on your server or if there is an alternative approach to handle SSL for these domains. Is that correct?

I have handled the subdomain certificate on my server, but I don't know what I can do for the ssl certificate of the domains that redirect users to my ip.